# The meaning of sigma_s and sigma_r in detailEnhance function on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, filter

The detailEnhance function provided by openCV have parameters InputArray, OutputArray, sigma_s and sigma_r. What does sigma s and r mean and what is it used for?

Here is the source: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/npr.html#detailenhance

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sigma_s` controls how much the image is smoothed - the larger its value, the more smoothed the image gets, but it's also slower to compute.

`sigma_r` is important if you want to preserve edges while smoothing the image. Small `sigma_r` results in only very similar colors to be averaged (i.e. smoothed), while colors that differ much will stay intact.

See also: https://www.learnopencv.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this really helps alot

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: By any chance, do you know why the float value in sigma_s is in a form of an int , while the float in sigma_r is in float value. void detailEnhance(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, float sigma_s=10, float sigma_r=0.15f)

Comment: That's because sigma_s corresponds to the size of the smoothing filter (i.e. the number of neighbouring pixels included while averaging the value), and sigma_r refers to the relative similarity between colors, which is easiest to express with a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Where do they actually start with the pixels? is it from left top to bottom right or which direction? sorry for asking these dumb questions :P

Comment: They use a mask, usually square-shaped, and they perform convolution (the mask slides across image). The order of operation and directions doesn't matter and it may depend on the implementation. These articles should help you understand:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)
https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/convolve.htm

Comment: BTW my advice: your last comment about pixels is pretty basic stuff in image processing, so it would be good for you to read about image processing in general, because without it you will have trouble understanding openCV docs.